# .htaccess route to different root folder depending on url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-routing, vagrant

In my server root I have 2 directories: `web_www` and `web_apps`.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
/
  /web_www
    /projectName
      index.php
  /web_apps
    /appProjectName
      index.php
```

If I enter `www.example.local/projectName`, I would like to be taken to the `index.php` file located at `/web_www/projectName/index.php`.

If I enter `www-apps.example.local/appProjectName`, I would like to be taken to the `index.php` file located at `/web_apps/appProjectName/index.php`.

What is the best method of doing this sort of configuration? I can either modify apache settings or use a .htaccess, but I am not entirely sure what I need to do.

Note that this is a local apache server using Vagrant.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web_www/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ /web_www/$1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web_apps/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ /web_apps/$1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Will you please elaborate on what these lines are doing? .htaccess looks like a foreign language to me.

Comment: also I need it to work for all my projects, not just the 2 samples provided -- the `web_www` and `web_apps` folders contain multiple domains inside of them.

Comment: @Prefix It looks at the first path node of the request (the "foo" part of `/foo/bar/`), and checks to see if it exists in `/web_www/`. If so, load the index.php file in that directory, if not, check if that path node exists in `/web_apps/`. If so, load the index.php file in that directory, otherwise do nothing and it will 404

Comment: @Prefix there's a lot of good documentation on Apache configuration and the mod_rewrite module. I would review the topics [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to get a better understanding of the details.